# использование vector с библиотекой boost

Tags: c++, vector

Ребят пытаюсь подключить библиотеку boost и использовать вместе с вектором. Выглядит примерно так:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

void Pollard(mp::cpp_int a, mp::cpp_int b, mp::cpp_int p)
{
    vector<mp::cpp_int> z(p+1),u(p+1),v(p+1);
    z[0] = 1;
    mp::cpp_int ph=phi(p);
    mp::cpp_int ak=0,ev=0,eu=0,nod,chk;
    mp::cpp_int p1 = p - 1;
    mp::cpp_int x = 0;
    for (mp::cpp_int i=0; i < p; i++)
    {
        if (z[i] % 3 == 1)
        {
            z[i + 1] = b * z[i]%p;
            u[i + 1] = u[i] % ph;
            v[i + 1] = (v[i] + 1) % ph;
        }
        if (z[i] % 3 == 2)
        {
            z[i + 1] = z[i] * z[i]%p;
            u[i + 1] = 2*u[i] % ph;
            v[i + 1] = 2*v[i] % ph;
        }
        if (z[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            z[i + 1] = a * z[i]%p;
            u[i + 1] = (u[i]+1) % ph;
            v[i + 1] = v[i] % ph;
        }
        if (*find(z.begin(), z.begin() + i, z[i + 1])!= *(z.begin() + i))
        {
            ak = distance(z.begin(),find(z.begin(), z.begin() + i, z[i + 1]));
            ev = v[ak] - v[i+1];
            if (ev < 0)
                ev += p1;
            eu = u[i+1] - u[ak];
            if (eu < 0)
                eu += p1;

void main()
{

}
```

Когда считаю `ue`, `ev` выдает ошибку у `v[ak]` и `u[ak]`:

> отсутствует оператор "[]", соответствующий этим операндам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то не видно, что такое ваше `i`, какой тип имеет.

Ну, а `ak` - это же переменная типа `mp::cpp_int`, она же в `size_t` неявно не приводится. А поскольку оператор `[]` от `mp::cpp_int` в векторе отсутствует, вот компилятор и ругается.

Comment: что подскажите сделать?

Comment: Не использовать для этих переменных этот тип. Если вам **нужен** этот тип (нельзя обойтись обычным `size_t`) - значит, у вас там такие величины, что все равно никакой памяти для вектора не хватит...

Comment: у меня работа с большими числами. Для маленьких чисел все прекрасно работает. Надо как-то сделать, чтобы с большими числами работать. Вектор нельзя использовать?

Comment: До этого использовал map с таким же типом, все прекрасно работает

Comment: Это разные индексы. Там вы можете использовать любой упорядочиваемый тип, а в векторе - нет. О больших числах... Ну давайте всего лишь представим тип `int` 4-байтный, и индекс такой же (*которого вам не хватает!*) - итого, максимальное значение 2^32 элементов по 4 байта - уже 16 гигабайт под вектор нужно...

Comment: С вектором я не смогу работать с таким типом? Даже, если использовать вектор из библиотеки boost?

Comment: Еще раз и медленно. Сколько элементов вектора вам нужно реально? Что вам не хватает в качестве индекса 4 миллиардов? Сколько места будет занимать такая память? Вам точно нужен вектор такого размера? Зачем вам столько элементов и сколько времени должна будет работать ваша программа? *Если для индексов не хватает обычного `size_t` - вы на неверном пути...*

Comment: Код подправил, чтобы понятно было. Размер вектора может быть очень большим 256 битным числом и следовательно работать тоже будет долго.

Comment: Размер вектора **не может быть большим 256-битным числом** - такая память просто не адресуется современными машинами... У вас количество байт памяти для этого вектора уже сравнимо с оценкой количества атомов во Вселенной (!).

Comment: а если 40 битное?

Comment: Лучше наверное перефразирую вопрос. С каким самым большим числом будет работать вектор и двумерный массив? Чтобы программу, можно было бы спокойно модифицировать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72178/discussion-between--and-harry).

Comment: Ну давайте прикинем. 2^40 элементов, как я понимаю, каждый элемент тоже такое же число - т.е. 40/8=5 байт. Итого требуется 5 терабайт на один массив, если, конечно, нет выравнивания и накладных расходов...

Comment: Понимаете, по-моему, вы все пытаетесь понять, как лучше держать микроскоп для забивания гвоздей, вместо того, чтоб выяснить, как забить гвоздь. Я имею в виду, что нужно не решать, как работать с массивами такого размера, а плясать от задачи - может, там массив очень разреженный или еще что... Скорее всего, надо полностью менять сам подход к решению задачи.

Comment: могу ли использовать unsigned __int64?

Comment: Просто как я понял  unsigned __int64?  имеет размер 8 байт. Что мне достаточно для числа.